# Laravel: Enforcing one to one relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an app in Laravel 5.

The app I'm creating is a recruitment site where a candidate must fill many forms. Because there are many fields, I decided to logically partition the `users` table into many smaller tables with one-to-one relationships.

For example two such tables may look like this:

**users**

- id
- role (e.g. admin or candidate)
- first_name
- surname
- dob

**driving_licences**

- id
- user_id (FK to users)
- has_licence
- number_of_points
- licence_number

In the above simple case, the `users` has a **one-to-one** relationship to `driving_licences`. In other words, every `User` model MUST have a single corresponding `DrivingLicence` model.

Creating the above table and corresponding Eloquent models is simple enough. However I am struggling as to the best approach to enforce that every user (or every user who is a candidate) has a corresponding `DrivingLicence`.

The solution I have currently is, whenever I use something from `DrivingLicence` I first check if the relationship exists and create it if it doesn't like so:

```
if ($user->drivingLicence === null) {
    $drivingLicence = new DrivingLicence();
    $drivingLicence->user_id = $user->id;
    $drivingLicence->save();
}
```

This has to be done every time I need to do something with `DrivingLicence`, which of course creates a LOT of repetition.

Therefore, my question is, how can I enforce that a one to one relationship exists between `users` and `driving_licences` in Laravel.

Comment: This likely isn't going to be the best way but could get you on the right track: create a function inside your `User` model to check if the license is null. If it is, create and save a new license for the user. `$user->checkLicense()`. In `checkLicense()` do your check for `null`, either create or fetch the license, and return the license. To be clear, this reduces the need to constantly rewrite the check for the license and moves it to a function inside your model.

Comment: Also, an idea to 'enforce' the required license is upon user creation you create an empty license to be saved when the user is saved. Then after the fact you can fill in the proper data. You'll no longer need to check if the license exists as you'll have created it when you create the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think forcing a user to have a license is the wrong goal in the first place. It's entirely possible that a user doesn't have a driving license, and instead of using the `has_license` field to indicate so, just don't create a driving license for them.

Think about it in a real-world scenario. People who don't have a driving license also don't have a card that says they don't have a license. That is basically what you're modelling with your current database schema. Instead, they just don't have anything, so omit the `driving_licenses` record.

Your `User` model could then have a method such as `hasDrivingLicense()` with the following implementation:

```
public function hasDrivingLicense()
{
    return $this->drivingLicense !== null;
}
```

I realise this doesn't answer your direct question, but this stood out to me as a bit of a code smell.

Comment: OK yes for this example. But for some other tables like `next_of_kin` or `documents` this is important.